# How do I declare a character array in MIPS assembler code?

Tags: c, arrays, mips

I have to translate some C code to MIPS assembler code and one of the lines is to declare the character array:

```
char name[100];
```

And I did:

```
.data
name: .space 100
```

But when assembling with MARS, I'm getting the error:

```
"name": operand is of incorrect type.
```

From what I understand, using `.space` can be used to declare the character array. Is there another way to declare the character array to combat this error?

Comment: So you mean a MIPS assembler. Which one?

Comment: I'm using MARS to assemble

Comment: I doubt that the error corresponds to the code you've shown in your question. What does the complete code you're trying to assemble look like?